# Got a problem in the first line, can't fix it

Tags: vba

I've got a porblem with the first line of my code, the thing is that i cant fix it for some reason.

```vb
Sub Main(numgen as Integer, letras as String, letra as String, celda as String)
    Call coincidir
    Dim numgen As Integer
    numgen = 0
    numgen = coincidir("Total general; A8:Z8; 0")
    numgen = numgen + 1

    Dim letras(1 To 25) As String

    letras(1) = "A"
    letras(2) = "B"
    letras(3) = "C"
    letras(4) = "D"
    letras(5) = "E"
    letras(6) = "F"
    letras(7) = "G"
    letras(8) = "H"
    letras(9) = "I"
    letras(10) = "J"
    letras(11) = "K"
    letras(12) = "L"
    letras(13) = "M"
    letras(14) = "N"
    letras(15) = "O"
    letras(16) = "P"
    letras(17) = "Q"
    letras(18) = "R"
    letras(19) = "S"
    letras(20) = "T"
    letras(21) = "U"
    letras(22) = "V"
    letras(23) = "W"
    letras(24) = "Y"
    letras(25) = "Z"

    Dim letra As String
    letra = "w"
    letras(numgen) = letra

    Dim celda As String
    celda = letra + "8"

    Range("celda").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Comisión"
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you clarify what error you're getting?

Comment: why you forget `X` ?

Comment: `Sub Main(numgen as Integer, letras as String, letra as String, celda as String)` you can declare again the variables in that line, delete all the `Dim numgen...` inside the procedure, they are already declared.

Answer (score 0):

Quite some errors in your code

1. Remove `Dim numgen As Integer` (already declared in first line)
2. You are populating one variable three times right after each other while it can be done in one row
3. Remove `Dim letra As String` after you already populated the array
4. Remove `Dim celda As String` (already declared in first line)
5. Remove `Dim letras As String` in first line
6. Avoid selecting or activating ranges
7. For some reason you're populating a range with a formula that's just a one-word string

should look something like:

```
Sub Main(numgen as Integer, letra as String, celda as String)
    Dim letras(1 To 25) as String
    Call coincidir
    numgen = coincidir("Total general; A8:Z8; 0") + 1 

    ''' ommitted

    letra = "w"
    letras(numgen) = letra

    celda = letra + "8"

    Workbooks(REF).Sheets(REF).Range("celda").Value= "Comisión"
End Sub
```

Doing something along the lines of `Sub test(sheetname As String, Nr As Long)` is usually done when you're calling the sub and you want to pass values to it.
For example:

```
Sub test()

i = Range("A1").Value
str = "Sheet3"

anothersub sheetname:= str, Nr:= i

End Sub

Sub anothersub(sheetname As String, Nr As Long)

Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Sheets(sheetname)

For i = 0 To Nr
    MsgBox i
Next i

End Sub
```

You're now declaring variables twice, which results in errors

Comment: Tim, `letras` is already declared as parameter to call `Main` either he changes the type or declares a new variable for the array.